# Bold a section of text by formula in a textbox on a report (ms Access 2016)

Tags: ms-access, formatting, report, ms-access-2016

I am trying to bold certain parts of concantenated text in a textbox.  The textbox's Control Source is:

="We would like to do a **Level " & [field1] & " analysis for you**.  We will do this **AND** do that."

I would like to format to bold from the word "Level" through the word "you", plus the word "AND".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the text format to *Rich Text*, you can use a limited form of HTML to bold things.

Then use the HTML `<strong>` tag to make text bold:

```
="We would like to do a <strong>Level " & [field1] & " analysis for you</strong>. We will do this <strong>AND</strong> do that."
```

Note that if Field1 contains plain text, you need to escape HTML characters like < and > if there are any.